# Getting closest to endpoints of (1,0) using np.random.uniform

Tags: python, numpy-random

-Random numbers can be drawn on the interval (0, 1], i.e., including 1 using:

```
import numpy as np
r = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=10)
```

I, however, want to generate numbers on the interval (0, 1), i.e., NOT including 1 and 0. Something like:

```
r = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0 - 2**-16, size=10)
```

Works, but how close can I theoretically get to 1 and 0, and is there a way to ensure that I can get as close to 1 as to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that `np.random.uniform` returns uniformly distributed random numbers on `[low, high)`, i.e., including `low` but not `high`. So I'm assuming you want to exclude `0` from your samples, not `1`.

In terms of how close you can *practically* get to zero, this is bounded by the precision of computer arithmetic. Assuming IEEE floating point numbers, as used by NumPy, the float closest to but greater than zero is given by:

```
>>> np.nextafter(0.0, 1.0) # Closest to 0.0 in direction of 1.0
5e-324
```

So to generate numbers on `(0, 1)`, you can do:

```
>>> np.random.uniform(low=np.nextafter(0.0, 1.0), high=1.0, size=10)
```

Comment: Didn't know `np.nextafter`, so thanks for showing me that. However,  `np.nextafter(0,1) == 1 - np.nextafter(1,0)` evaluates to `false` which seems to imply that there is an asymmetry in how close one can get to 0 and 1?

Comment: @edager Yes, that's right. Floating point means that the decimal point "floats". So in contrast to fixed precision, which has the same number of digits after the decimal for any number, the precision of each number varies with its magnitude. The difference between 1000 and the next largest number is much larger than the difference between 0 and its next number, which is why functions like `np.nextafter()` exists. I suggest [reading more about IEEE-754](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) floating point representations.